# using matched results from php's preg_match function

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to extract specific id from a webpage using php ,curl and  preg-match.
I can print the result but it does not work well when i am trying to make another curl using this id.
i tried to trim the matched result (id) before curling again but did not work.

```
$pattern = '#result_id=(.*?)&#';
preg_match($pattern, $content, $searchId);
$link = 'www.xyz.com/results?result_id='.$searchId[1];
```

Comment: What is the result of an `echo($link);`?

Comment: What if you use `$pattern = '#result_id=([^&]+)#';`? However, it seems the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: www.xyz.com/results?result_id=kc0dI83x

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does not work either, i don't think the pattern i the problem because it prints the result as it should be .

Comment: If it's echoing correctly, the problem is probably elsewhere.